# How to speed up time to upgrade a DB to a superior Data Service Tier in SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am experimenting with the new SQL Azure Data Tiers. I have created a new DB from an import of an old "Web Edition" DB(DB1) and set it up as a "Standard S1"(DB2). All fine. This took about 5 minutes. However if I try and upgrade this DB1 again by using "Scale", it takes much longer. For my 250 mb, MS's calculation says 20 minutes :

```
3 x (5 minutes + database size / 150 MB/minute)
```

So I am minded to upgrade via:

1) Export DB1(Web)

2) Import DB1(Web) to DB2(as Standard S2).

It seems much quicker.

Am I missing a trick here/ misunderstood something ? Is it that doing it via "Scale" means that the DB is not taken offline, but because of this, it takes longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scaling up a db is a complete online operation without a down time. I would recommend going with this approach as in future Microsoft may optimize things. Import / export approach appears to be a brute force for me. You also end up paying more with the other approach as you have two billable databases at one point. Today it appears both the approaches are order of data operation.

Comment: Thanks for this, appreciate the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

On the back end a scale operation will do one of two things it will either synchronize a new database (copy the data to a new node which has capacity) or it will just upgrade you to the new tier if capacity is available on the node you are currently on.

As such there is some variable amount of time it can take to go from one tier to another. In my opinion though most of the time it goes much faster than the calculation provided on the site.

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree, just found my 20 minute prediction completed in 12 minutes. So perhaps the "scale" approach is still the best approach. Still learning here :)

Comment: I definitely suggest the scale approach, in this situation your database is still up and usable even if it isn't the new SLO for a few minutes.